Is it possible to use slotted dataclasses with SQLAlchemy's ORM?
I'm using dataclasses and SQLAlchemy ORM to send data to a (My)SQL database.
Although not a requirement, I would like to store data entries in a slotted dataclass, but have run into an error when doing so. If it is not possible to use slots on the data model dataclass, any further insights into why/what causes this behaviour would be gratefully received. I have included a short example script that reproduces the error at the end.
Thank you in advance!
The error: when attempting to initialise the mapped class with data, I receive the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/.../example.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(Example(**example_data))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/home/python/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 551, in _new_state_if_none
    self._state_setter(instance, state)
  File "<string>", line 1, in set
AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Example code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3.11
# coding: utf-8

""" 
Python v. 3.11.5
SQLAlchemy v. 2.0.23

Example script demonstrating 'sa_instance_state' error:
    AttributeError: 'Example' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
"""

from dataclasses import dataclass

from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import PrimaryKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import registry


metadata_obj = MetaData()


@dataclass(slots=True, weakref_slot=True)
class Example:
    f1: str


example = Table(
    "example",
    metadata_obj,
    Column("f1", String),
    PrimaryKeyConstraint("f1", name="example_pk"),
)


example_data = {"f1": "1"}

print(Example(**example_data))  # 'Example(f1='1')', as expected

mapper_registry = registry()
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Example, example)

print(Example(**example_data))  # errors



You get the AttributeError because there is no slot for _sa_instance_state, so I suspect for the time being the answer is "no".

Currently not supported are the frozen and slots features.
